# MVC error encounted

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing an application using MVC 5 when I run it I got this error

> Compilation Error    Description: An error occurred during the
>   compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please
>   review the following specific error details and modify your source
>   code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'template'
>   could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Source Error:

```
Line 28:     
Line 29:     
Line 30:     public class _Page_Views_Emergence_Index_cshtml : System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<IEnumerable<template.model.emergenceview>> {
Line 31:         
Line 32: #line hidden
```

> Source File: d:\local\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\9c72e46c\a2166d6c\App_Web_index.cshtml.4574e8d.-zs3j30-.0.cs
>   Line: 30

Comment: Have you included your `template` reference? if you are using Visual Studio click on the word `template` and press Ctrl + . and it will come up with some options to generate the class or include it

Answer (score 1):

This error clearly indicates that you model `IEnumerable<template.model.emergenceview>` cannot be resolved because `template` namespace cannot be found. Make sure that namespace is correct(it is case-sensitive) and it wasn't renamed/removed.